# Android: Navigation using Tab key doesn't work properly on input boxes

Tags: android, browser, cordova, android-softkeyboard

For large size screens, the default android keyboard automatically displays Tab keys. I have a phonegap application which contains several input boxes on one page. When I try to navigate between input boxes using tab key on soft-keyboard, nothing happens.

I also tried to open gmail login page on browser and Tab key didn't shift focus there as well. However, I noticed that only in case of input boxes, I had to use shift+tab key to navigate to next input box. For navigating between other elements, just pressing tab key was sufficient. Is this the specific behavior implemented by android & is there any particular reason for it? I am using nexus 10 but found same behavior on emulator too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a problem with Nexus 10 in particular, as I observe the same thing and here is another user that reports the same (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651669/nexus-10-keyboard-tab-key-not-working).

Tab key does work on native Android apps as it is supposed to, but not on hybrid apps which are basically wrapped in WebView. I think this is an oversight from the Android team. You can always install a Swipe or Hackers keyboard from the Play Store where the Tab key does the job.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue specific to Android Tablet devices. A workaround I found was to change the keyboard mode to either split or floating. Also I noticed flipping the device around to landscape view allows the input elements to behave correctly.

The original issue is related to the viewport size change that happens when any input receives focus which is caused by this so-called soft keyboard. Android seems to handle the rendering of a soft keyboard differently from other manufacturers.